# How to define "complex Float64" variable in Julia?

Tags: julia

I have a module, say, called Constants,

```
module Constants
const zero = 0.0 :: Float64
const czero = 0.0 + 0.0im :: Complex
end
```

I know like I can define like zero as Float64. But How do I define a "Complex" and "Float64" variable such as czero? Currently I use Complex, but I want to be more specific. If I use ComplexF64

```
const czero = 0.0 + 0.0im :: ComplexF64
```

it gives me an error,

```
ERROR: LoadError: TypeError: in typeassert, expected Complex{Float64}, got a value of type Complex{Bool}
```

So what concrete type of Complex should I use?
I give each variable a concrete type is because I heard that if the code looks like Fortran it can run like Fortran, because I define the type first so Julia do not have to convert the type which can be very slow.

Comment: The TypeError is because this is parsed as `0.0 + 0.0(im :: ComplexF64)`, you're asserting that `im` is of type `ComplexF64`, but wanted `(0.0 + 0.0im)::ComplexF64`. As noted below, you probably don't want to do this anyway.

Comment: Note that by convention in Julia you do not put space before and after `::`. This is just a style issue

Comment: I removed again `fortran`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  ::

  With the ::-operator type annotations are attached to expressions and variables in programs. See the manual section on Type Declarations.

  Outside of declarations :: is used to assert that expressions and variables in programs have a given type.

  Examples
  ≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡

  julia> (1+2)::AbstractFloat
  ERROR: TypeError: typeassert: expected AbstractFloat, got a value of type Int64
  
  julia> (1+2)::Int
  3
```

With this in mind, obviously julia considers the declaration invalid because of operator precedence, so just put parentheses if you want to do the declaration this way

```
const czero = (0.0 + 0.0im) ::ComplexF64
```

**I also second the opinion above**: if you're just trying to declare zeros then what you need is `zero`

Answer (score 4):

This question is not quite clear, but perhpas what you need is `zero`:

```
julia> zero(ComplexF64)
0.0 + 0.0im

julia> dump(zero(ComplexF64))
ComplexF64
  re: Float64 0.0
  im: Float64 0.0
```

Other options include using the constructor such as `ComplexF64(0.0)` or `ComplexF64(0.0,0.0)` or using the `complex(0.0)` function. These are all type stable.